# Using localStorage to update another tabs content isn't working all the times

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a page (page #1) on my website where the content is loaded by making a call to an API.

Then I have another page (page #2) on my website that POSTs some data into the API and saves some content into it. This new content should be visible into page #1 and it does when the page #1 is refreshed (as it makes the API call again).

I wanted to make the content on page #1 update programmatically without needing to refresh the page, when page #1 and page #2 are both opened in the browser of the user, so page #1 doesn't need to be refreshed to see that there is new content in there.

To do so, I thought of creating a localStorage item to specify that new content has been added to the API on page #2:

```
axios.post(apiURL + "save", 
{
    id: myID,
    data: myData
})
.then(response => {
    localStorage.setItem("update-profile", true); //<-- Here
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Then, on page #1 I have a listener that checks when my localStorage item is added and reloads the content of the page making a new API call:

```
window.addEventListener("storage", updateProfile);

const updateProfile = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("update-profile") !== null) {
        axios.get(apiURL + "get")
        .then(response => updateContent())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

        localStorage.removeItem("update-profile"); //<-- Removes localStorage item
    }
}
```

The issue here is that this whole thing works like 70% of the times. Sometimes, seems like the item isn't added properly to localStorage on page #2. Is there any way I could fix this to make it work 100% of the times? Is there any other better technique to achieve this in a consistent way?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) instead for a potentially smoother experience:

```js
// page 1 + 2
const profile = new BroadcastChannel("profile");

bc.onmessage = (event) => {
  // update profile on this page
};

function changeProfile(profileData) {
    profile.postMessage(profileData);
}
```